# Query with partial fields of composite key is throwing exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have table say `SomeObject`, which has following fields:

```
Field_1 (Primary key)
Field_2 (Primary key)
Field_3 (Primary key)
Field_4
Field_5
```

where `Field_1, Field_2 & Field_3` forms composite primary key(we are using JPA with hibernate). I have written NamedQuery and its where clause includes :

```
CompKey.Field_1 = value1 AND CompKey.Field_2 = value2 AND Field_4 = value4.
```

While executing this named query, I am getting error : Field_3 cannot accept NULL value.

Any suugestion what is it wrong here.

Comment: Please post the complete query generated by hibernate.

Comment: 'FROM SomeObject po 
WHERE po.someObjectPK.Field_1 =:value1 
AND po.someObjectPK.Field_2 =:value2 
AND po.Field_4 =:value4'

Comment: @user3671048, update your question and add complete details like what is the query you have written, the query generated by hibernate & the exception with its stacktrace when you run the program.